# Is it possible to overwrite Filestack popin title?

Tags: javascript, upload, overwrite, filestack

I have a question about Filestack.

i'm using it to upload a CSV files but i have to tell to user(s) some information about this CSV file.

I would like to write it in the title of the popin Filestack :
[popin Filestack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LD5O.png)

I'd like to do something like remove the computer icone to write some text .

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a paid account or the free version? The picker is only customizable for paid users. There is a free trial if you want to try it.